# How can I get the resource in src/main/resources/upload-dir?

Tags: java, spring, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The tree of my project is:

```
+---.mvn
|   \---wrapper
+---.settings
+---src
|   +---main
|   |   +---java
|   |   |   \---com
|   |   |       +---google
|   |   |       |   \---api
|   |   |       |       \---services
|   |   |       |           \---samples
|   |   |       |               \---youtube
|   |   |       |                   \---cmdline
|   |   |       |                       \---data
|   |   |       \---musicnet
|   |   |           \---springboot
|   |   |               +---basicauth
|   |   |               +---controller
|   |   |               +---exception
|   |   |               +---model
|   |   |               +---repository
|   |   |               \---service
|   |   \---resources
|   |       +---static
|   |       |   +---css
|   |       |   +---img
|   |       |   \---js
|   |       +---templates
|   |       \---upload-dir
|   \---test
|       \---java
|           \---com
|               \---musicnet
|                   \---springboot
\---target
    +---classes
    |   +---com
    |   |   +---google
    |   |   |   \---api
    |   |   |       \---services
    |   |   |           \---samples
    |   |   |               \---youtube
    |   |   |                   \---cmdline
    |   |   |                       \---data
    |   |   \---musicnet
    |   |       \---springboot
    |   |           +---basicauth
    |   |           +---controller
    |   |           +---exception
    |   |           +---model
    |   |           +---repository
    |   |           \---service
    |   +---META-INF
    |   |   \---maven
    |   |       \---com.musicnet
    |   |           \---musicnet
    |   +---static
    |   |   +---css
    |   |   \---js
    |   +---templates
    |   \---upload-dir
    \---test-classes
        \---com
            \---musicnet
                \---springboot
```

I am uploading videos which are under src/main/resources/upload-dir with UploadVideo.java which is in com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data.

Src/main/resources is configured on classpath:

```
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```

UploadVideo.java returns null in line:

```
InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT, UploadVideo.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + SAMPLE_VIDEO_FILENAME));
```

I was reading and trying several ways to introduce or configure the path in getResourceAsStream to my video but always return null. The only way it works is when my upload-dir is under package com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data. So can I put relative path from com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data until src/main/resources/upload-dir?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can load files from resources dir with Spring easily.

Get or create an app context:

```
appContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext()
```

Then obtain the resource you want:

```
res = appContext.getResource("classpath:upload-dir/targetvideo.mkv")
```

Then you can get the inputstream from the res variable.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am checking that seems to be not synchronized when file is upload to file system server and appContext is created. In order to be more specific:
- First the file is upload from view to file system server.
- Then the youtube api is called in order to upload the video to youtube.
- Youtube api create the resource and upload it to youtube.
- But the first time that upload video, the resource is null. If I restard project from Eclipse (some times I have to close Eclipse and open again) and try the same process, the resource is ok and then video is uploaded to Youtube.

It's like video is saved on file system server but appContext doesn't find the video on file system. Restart the project is needed in order to appContext find the video.

I have tryied to fix that marking in Windows -> Preferences -> WorkSpace -> Refresh using native hooks or pooling and Project -> Build automatically but the problem still persist.